# Activated Route Angular no trae los datos desde mongodb

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy usando Activated Route Angular para obtener un actor con sus peliculas, tengo una lista de actores, en donde cada actor tiene un enlace Activated Route a los detalles con sus peliculas.

En mi servicio estoy usando

```
getActor(_id:String): Observable<Actorpelicula>{
const url = `${this.URL_ACT}/${_id}`;

return this.http.get<Actorpelicula>(url)
```

}

En el componente

```
     getActor():void{
    const _id = this.rutas.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');
    this.peliculaService.getActor(_id)
    .subscribe(actor => this.actor = actor);
  }
```

Desde mi controlador estoy usando esta consulta que funciona, pero no me trae todos los detalles que estoy necesitando en la consulta

```
peliculaCtrl.getActor = async(req, res) =>{
const actor = await Actores.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
res.json(actor);
```

};

Me devuelve un documento con la estructura

```
 {
  "_id": "5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3",
  "name": "Keanu Reeves",
  "description": "es un actor y músico canadiense-estadounidense, nacido en el Líbano. Dedicado a la actuación, tiene entre su repertorio las comedias de la franquicia de Bill y Ted (1989–1991); los thrillers de acción Point Break (1991), Speed (1994) y la franquicia John Wick (2014–2019); el thriller psicológico The Devil's Advocate (1997); el thriller sobrenatural Constantine (2005); y la serie de ciencia ficción y acción The Matrix (1999-2003). También ha participado en películas dramáticas como Dangerous Liaisons (1988), My Own Private Idaho (1991) y Little Buddha (1993), así como en la película de terror y romance Bram Stoker's Dracula (1992).",
  "height": "1.86",
  "birth": "1964-09-02T05:00:00.000Z",
  "years": 55,
  "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/tq/image/upload/v1572888170/cineencasa/actores/bOlYWhVuOiU6azC4Bw6zlXZ5QTC.jpg",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Esta nueva consulta tiene los detalles necesarios que necesito

```
peliculaCtrl.peliculasActor = async(req,res) =>{

const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

const peliculaActor = await Actores.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: ObjectId(req.params.id)
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "peliculas",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "cast",
          as: "peliculas"
        }
   }
 ])

 res.json(peliculaActor);
}
```

Si realizo la solicitud a la ruta me devuelve, donde se evidencia que este actor participa en 3 peliculas

```
       [
  {
    "_id": "5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3",
    "name": "Keanu Reeves",
    "description": "es un actor y músico canadiense-estadounidense, nacido en el Líbano. Dedicado a la actuación, tiene entre su repertorio las comedias de la franquicia de Bill y Ted (1989–1991); los thrillers de acción Point Break (1991), Speed (1994) y la franquicia John Wick (2014–2019); el thriller psicológico The Devil's Advocate (1997); el thriller sobrenatural Constantine (2005); y la serie de ciencia ficción y acción The Matrix (1999-2003). También ha participado en películas dramáticas como Dangerous Liaisons (1988), My Own Private Idaho (1991) y Little Buddha (1993), así como en la película de terror y romance Bram Stoker's Dracula (1992).",
    "height": "1.86",
    "birth": "1964-09-02T05:00:00.000Z",
    "years": 55,
    "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/tq/image/upload/v1572888170/cineencasa/actores/bOlYWhVuOiU6azC4Bw6zlXZ5QTC.jpg",
    "__v": 0,
    "peliculas": [
      {
        "_id": "5d4d9a2f2d58315258aa1b48",
        "gender": "Acción",
        "cast": "Keanu Reeves",
        "cast1": null,
        "cast2": null,
        "cast3": null,
        "cast4": null,
        "coverp": "https://res.cloudinary.com/tq/image/upload/v1568603864/cineencasa/busqueda-implacable-3.jpg",
        "date": null,
        "duration": null,
        "gender1": "Crimen",
        "gender2": null,
        "linkdown": null,
        "linkdown1": null,
        "linkdown2": null,
        "linkdown3": null,
        "linkdown4": null,
        "linkview": null,
        "linkview1": null,
        "linkview2": null,
        "linkview3": null,
        "linkview4": null,
        "overview": null,
        "popular": null,
        "premiere": null,
        "score": null,
        "title": "Búsqueda Implacable",
        "year": null,
        "datepremiere": "2019-10-07T01:17:54.000Z",
        "duration1": null,
        "triler": null
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d509cee2d58315258aa1b4f",
        "gender": "Acción",
        "cast": "Keanu Reeves",
        "cast1": null,
        "cast2": null,
        "cast3": null,
        "cast4": null,
        "coverp": "https://res.cloudinary.com/tq/image/upload/v1568603865/cineencasa/el-justiciero-2.jpg",
        "date": null,
        "duration": null,
        "gender1": "Animación",
        "gender2": "Comedia",
        "linkdown": null,
        "linkdown1": null,
        "linkdown2": null,
        "linkdown3": null,
        "linkdown4": null,
        "linkview": null,
        "linkview1": null,
        "linkview2": null,
        "linkview3": null,
        "linkview4": null,
        "overview": null,
        "popular": null,
        "premiere": null,
        "score": null,
        "title": "El Justiciero",
        "year": null,
        "datepremiere": null,
        "duration1": null
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d59623f2c933a333417c29e",
        "title": "10x10",
        "overview": "Todos estaban en el templo",
        "year": 2019,
        "cast": "Keanu Reeves",
        "cast1": "Pedro",
        "cast2": "Juan",
        "cast3": "Luisa",
        "cast4": "Daniela",
        "coverp": "https://res.cloudinary.com/tq/image/upload/v1569103089/cineencasa/10x10.jpg",
        "gender": "Documental",
        "gender1": "Drama",
        "gender2": "Familia",
        "duration": 1.56,
        "date": "2019-08-18T14:26:18.571Z",
        "score": 8.9,
        "popular": true,
        "premiere": true,
        "linkview": "http:111",
        "linkview1": "http:222",
        "linkview2": "http:3",
        "linkview3": "http:4",
        "linkview4": "http:5",
        "linkdown": "htttdescarga1",
        "linkdown1": "htttdescarga2",
        "linkdown2": "htttdescarga3",
        "linkdown3": "htttdescarga4",
        "linkdown4": "htttdescarga5",
        "__v": 0,
        "datepremiere": null,
        "duration1": null,
        "triler": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Pero en el DOM obtengo los campos vacios, creo que es por la estructura en la que me devuelve la consulta el documento, lo unico diferente que logro evidenciar es que usando `Actores.findOne({_id: req.params.id})` mme devuelve el documento en `{...}` y con `Actores.aggregate([])` me devuelve el documento `[{...}]`

Espero me puedan ayudar amigos

Comment: Hola @esteban-rua, comentarte que el método `aggregate` siempre te devuelve un array, por eso al cambiar tu query en vez de devolverte el documento como el `findOne` te devuelve el array. 
Una pregunta, porque realizas un `$lookup` de la colección `películas` si luego con el `$project` no devuelves el campo `peliculas`?

Comment: Hola en realidad lo que necesito es que me devuelva las peliculas en las que ese actor participa de esta forma sin usar `$project`
`[
    {
      "_id": "5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3",
      "name": "",
      "description": "",
      "height": "",
      "birth": "",
      "years": 55,
      "image": "...",
      "__v": 0,
      "peliculas": [
        {
            }]`

Comment: Hola, podrías editar la pregunta añadiendo el documento que necesitas?

Comment: Listo claro ya lo hago